# How can I draw dots in a rooted tree structure graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, graphs, trees, tikz-graphs

I wrote this code but I would like to add dots between the points to indicate that there are more points between the points I draw.

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge = {Stealth-},
    grow = north
            }
[ $e(x)$
   [$\begin{matrix}
       \vdots\\
       f_{n_f}^{-1}(e(x))
   \end{matrix}$]
    [$\begin{matrix}
        \vdots \\
        f_{2}^{-1}(e(x))
    \end{matrix}$]
    
    [$f_{1}^{-1}(e(x))$,
        [$\begin{matrix}
          \vdots\\
          f_{n_f}^{-1}(f_{2}^{-1}(e(x)))
      \end{matrix}$]  
       [$\begin{matrix}
          \vdots\\
          f_{2}^{-2}(e(x))
      \end{matrix}$]
      [$\begin{matrix}
          \vdots\\
        f_{1}^{-1}(f_{2}^{-1}(e(x)))
      \end{matrix}$]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The graph should look like this:

[image]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. If the horizontal dots indicate more inverse functions, put an arrow from the dots to the item below. Also I would reposition the middle function in the middle row so vertical dots do not seem like they come from the function above. Possibly I am misinterpreting your diagram.

Comment: `[leaf [$\vdots$, no edge]]` gives you dots above the `leaf`. The same can be done for the horizontal `\dots`. I don't quite understand why you're using `matrix` here.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `tikz-cd` for this. The dots can either occupy their own cells or be labels for phantom arrows, depending on the spacing you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrow style=tikz, >={latex}, column sep=3mm]
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
f_1^{-1}\big(e(x)\big)\arrow[drr] & f_2^{-1}\big(e(x)\big)\arrow[dr] & \cdots & f_{n_f}^{-1}\big(e(x)\big)\arrow[dl]\arrow[d, phantom, sloped, "\dots"] & & \arrow[d, phantom, sloped, "\dots"]\\
 & & f_1^{-1}\big(e(x)\big)\arrow[drr] & f_2^{-1}\big(e(x)\big)\arrow[dr] & \cdots & f_{n_f}^{-1}\big(e(x)\big)\arrow[dl]\\
 & & & & e(x)
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```